# Dynamically Loaded UserControl Loading DropDownList Items Once Disappear on PostBack

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, webforms, user-controls

Technology: Asp.Net 4.5

I have a project that will potentially be loading hundreds of different dynamic user controls. One at a time of course, depending on the user selection. The usercontrol interfaces will be populated from database upon loading it.

When dynamically loading a usercontrol with dropdownlist, I only want to load in the items once. However the items disappear on postback. I am using the Page_Load in usercontrol to populate dropdown. I've tried OnInit as well. Nothing I've tried so far seems to work.

Strangely enough if I invoke a method in the usercontrol from the main page then the items persist on every postback without having to repopulate the items everytime.

I would prefer to load the items once when the user control is added. Here is the sample code (very simple)

MainPage - Aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false"   CodeBehind="WebForm5.aspx.vb" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm5" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Load User Control" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="PostBack" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Invoke Method" />
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
        </asp:Panel>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

MainPage - CodeBehind

```
Public Class WebForm5
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Request.Form(Button1.UniqueID) IsNot Nothing Then
        Session("IsLoading") = True
        Panel1.Controls.Clear()
    End If

    If IsPostBack = True Then
        Dim MyControl As UserControl = Page.LoadControl("UserControls\UcTest.ascx")
        MyControl.ID = "UcTest"
        MyControl.EnableViewState = True
        Panel1.Controls.Add(MyControl)
    End If

End Sub

Protected Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

    Dim uc As UserControl = Panel1.FindControl("UcTest")
    If uc IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim s As String = ""
        Dim method As System.Reflection.MethodInfo = uc.GetType.GetMethod("LoadItems")
        If method IsNot Nothing Then
            method.Invoke(uc, New Object() {s})
        End If
    End If

End Sub

End Class
```

**EDIT** - this fixed the issue based on Ann's answer. Use the PreInit instead of Page_Load

```
  Private Sub WebForm5_PreInit(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.PreInit
    If Request.Form(Button1.UniqueID) IsNot Nothing Then
        Session("IsLoading") = True
        Panel1.Controls.Clear()
    End If

    If IsPostBack = True Then
        Panel1.Controls.Clear()
        Dim MyControl As UserControl = Page.LoadControl("UserControls\UcTest.ascx")
        MyControl.ID = "UcTest"
        MyControl.EnableViewState = False
        Panel1.Controls.Add(MyControl)
        MyControl.EnableViewState = True
    End If

End Sub
```

UserControl - Aspx

```
<%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="UcTest.ascx.vb" Inherits="WebApplication1.UcTest" %>

<br />
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Width="150" AutoPostBack="false" EnableViewState="True">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

UserControl - CodeBehind

```
Public Class UcTest
Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Session("IsLoading") = True Then

        'To be populated from database in the real app
        'Simplified here for testing

        DropDownList1.Items.Add("Red")
        DropDownList1.Items.Add("Green")
        DropDownList1.Items.Add("Blue")
        Session("IsLoading") = False
    End If

End Sub

Public Sub LoadItems(s As String)
    DropDownList1.Items.Add("Red")
    DropDownList1.Items.Add("Green")
    DropDownList1.Items.Add("Blue")
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: That's definitely not c#.

Comment: This is what one might call Visual Basic if I´m correct

Comment: The auto tag suggestions got me. Either way one should be able to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per Microsoft's [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx), your dynamically-added controls will need to be present by the time `ViewState` is loaded if you want to recover their values.  Loading from `ViewState` happens between the `Initialization` and `Load` stages.

Microsoft recommends re-creating them in `PreInit`:
[image]

Comment: Thanks Ann, you were correct. I did move the code to PreInit but forgot to clear controls on every postback first from the panel. Once I did that it worked as intended I will add the alternative code to the original posting.

Comment: Without this website I would cry.